# React - cant find module - trying to pass cell image path variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why does this work.

```
function imageFormatter(cell, row){  
  return <img src={require('../img/myImage.jpg)'} />;
}
```

But this will not work.

```
function asMyQuote(input) {
  return '\'' + input + '\'';
}

function imageFormatter(cell, row){  
  var celly = asMyQuote(cell);
  console.log("IMAGEFORMATTER CELLy::",celly);
   return <img src={require(celly)} />;
 }
```

My console.log says

```
IMAGEFORMATTER CELLy:: '../img/myImage.jpg'
```

Yet my page will not render successfully.  DOM error following the console log is.

```
 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module ''../img/myImage.jpg''.
```

I know I have a hacky function for the quotes but im just trying to figure out where my problem is.  I don't think it's the single quotes.  Im starting to wonder if I have a problem with webpack or something.

I using a React-bootstrap-table module and im trying to insert a image into a cell.  my {data} i've collected has the path for the pic, which is what im trying to pass through. Here is my bootstrap table just in case.

```
       <BootstrapTable data={Evt1} hover selectRow={ selectRowProp } bodyStyle={ { background: '#f4a442' } }>
      <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='pk_id_competitor'>compId</TableHeaderColumn>
<TableHeaderColumn dataField='pic' dataFormat={imageFormatter}>pic</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='rname'>rname</TableHeaderColumn>          
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='hname'>hname</TableHeaderColumn>
      <TableHeaderColumn dataField='eventtier'>eventtier</TableHeaderColumn>
    </BootstrapTable>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack examines the source of your program to determine which assets to include. By changing the require statement from a static string (which could be mapped directly to a file on your disk) to a dynamic variable, it is no longer able to satisfy the dependency. Check this out for more on how you can do dynamic requires: https://webpack.github.io/docs/context.html

My suggestion would be to constrain the dynamic images to be in a certain directory, along the lines of:

```
function imageFormatter(cell, row){  
    return <img src={require('../img/' + cell)} />;
}
```

You can also use the `require.context` API, which allows you to provide more information to webpack:

```
// look in ../img, allow subdirectories, and satisfy requests for all jpgs, pngs, and gifs therein
// this will add all of these images to your final bundle!
var imageRequirer = require.context('../img', true, /^\.\/.*\.(jpg|png|gif)$/

function imageFormatter(cell, row){  
    return <img src={imageRequirer(cell)} />;
}
```

Comment: That quick work around works fine. I'll make sure to read up more on the webpack site you provided.  So far my experience with Webpack has been pretty painful.  Thanks very much for the quick help.  Answer accepted!

Comment: @Eric, you are awesome.